# How to send the Response the request Post to save on database? NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm doing the method `Post` with `axios.js` and `node.js` and it's working. It does the request but the request does not save the data to database.

My `axios.js` where i do the request:

```js
teste = () => {
  axios.post('/api/post', {
      firstName: 'Marlon',
      lastName: 'Bernardes'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    });
}
```

My route `post`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const dao = require('../matchs-dao.js');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/post', async(req, res) => {
  const response = await dao.post();
  res.send(
    response
  )
});

module.exports = router;
```

My route post await the DAO, look it:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
  post() {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3004/score')
      .then(response =>
        response.data)
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

}
```

The result of the my method `post`
[image]

Server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const rotas = require('./rotas')
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("was")
});

app.use('/api', rotas);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server rodando na porta 3001')
})
```

The route `post` is inside the `/api`..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would want know how i do to save to database.

Comment: If you call dao.post probably you should pass data object as a parameter and then pass this object to axios.post as the second parameter. And what is the method teste for what?

Comment: You would can show me, how? Please?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/axios/axios documentation in POST method, you should pass the second parameter as the request body. Like in your function teste.

Router:

```
const express = require('express');
const dao = require('../matchs-dao.js');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/post', async(req, res) => {
    const response = await dao.post(dataObject);
    res.send(response)
});

module.exports = router;
```

DAO:

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    post(data) {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:3004/score', data)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some error? Do your request success? Did you get data on the backend?

Comment: Yes, gave success. But the datas not go to database.

Comment: In the console, appears the `data` but i refresh the database but it's empty :(

Comment: between database and UI there is backand. Probably problem on BE. Can you provide BE function?

Comment: Please provide file rotas I can't say what is wrong just by this example. Where is the BE code with request to database and POST handler ?